# jqGrid grouping - hiding the group header and footer when only one row

Tags: jquery, jqgrid

I use the grouping feature in a jqGrid. 
But I want to display the group header (jqgroup) and group footer (jqfoot) only when there is more than one element in the group.

I am trying to do it with JQuery selectors in the *loadComplete* callback.
I have already succeeded in hiding the group header by checking the number of items in the group header text.

```
groupingView : { 
  ..
  groupText: ['<b>{0}</b> ({1})'],
}

loadComplete: function(data) {     
  // group header text is "value (number of elements)"
  $("#grid tr.jqgroup:contains('(1)')").hide(); 
}
```

But I cannot find the correct selector to hide the group summary row. 
I have tried the following for example:

```
$("#grid tr.jqgroup:contains('(1)') + .jqfoot")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found it in fact: "+" operator gives the really next element

```
$("#grid tr.jqgroup:contains('(1)') + .jqgrow + .jqfoot").hide();
```